# How is logarithm function important in minimization/maximization algorithm?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, logarithms

I always saw the algorithm transform its objective function by $\log$. I wonder this is because logarithm function is monotonically increased ($\log x$) to do maximization, or decreased ($-\log x$) to do minimization? So for MM algorithm, any functions should be transformed into $\log$?

Are there also other reasons that $\log$ transformation is often used? I wonder log is always work or we have some mathematical operations that can replace $\log$ for this purpose?

Comment: It is also a commonly used transformation since it gets rid of exponents in the objective function, which makes it easier to differentiate while preserving the maxima and minima.

Answer (score 3):

The logarithm is used for the "logarithmic derivative" trick, which turns products into sums. This is useful because the functions to optimize are often products, often with exponentials, and detection of the extrema requires differentiation.

$$(\log abc)'=\frac{(abc)'}{abc}=\frac{a'}a+\frac{b'}b+\frac{c'}c$$ is more manageable than $a'bc+ab'c+abc'$ when the factors are complex.

Comment: I think another reason is that by employing products, the floating-point numbers are a bit out of control for precise calculations; small numbers get smaller and underflow may occur.

Comment: @Media: numerical problems (catastrophic cancellation) appear with additions, not multiplications.

Comment: Yes, sure. I wanted to say this also occurs near points where the gradients are so small, and the product of values can get even smaller. Underflow, in this case, may occur.